# Why two Apis calls are made when I call once

Tags: angular, api

I am using angular4. When I make an API call and look in chrome dev tools. it is showing me as two api calls for post.

1. without post body and there is no response.
2. with post body and I am getting response from this.

But I like to know why there are two API calls made?

Comment: Are both requests of type `POST`? Is the first one of type `OPTIONS`?

Comment: Probably something going on with observables but without code, we're not wizard and can't help you

Comment: Read about CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in first API the method is 'OPTIONS' which call is made automatically if you are using CORS plugin in chrome.

Comment: So you just post my comment as an answer? nice.